# Debug QGIS3 plugin with Visual Studio Code

Tags: qgis, debugging, visual-studio-code

I would like debug QGIS plugin using Visual Studio Code. I have Win10 and QGIS 3.4.4. I followed the instructions written in these two sites:

1. [How to setup QGIS 3 and Visual Studio Code plugin development (Windows)](http://gis-expert.com/wp/2018/10/15/how-to-setup-qgis-3-and-visual-studio-code-plugin-development-windows/)
2. [Debug Visual Studio plugin homepage](https://github.com/lmotta/debug_vs_plugin/wiki)

When I start the debug in visual studio code I have the follow error message:

Exception in thread ptvsd.Server:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS
>   3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 269, in process_one_message  msg = self.__message.pop(0) IndexError: pop from
>   empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
>           self.run()
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
>           self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 712, in process_messages
>           raise exc
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 697, in process_messages
>           self.process_messages()
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 258, in process_messages
>           self.process_one_message()
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 272, in process_one_message
>           self._wait_for_message()
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 154, in _wait_for_message
>           line = self._buffered_read_line_as_ascii()
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 113, in _buffered_read_line_as_ascii
>           temp = self.__socket.recv(1024)
>       socket.timeout: timed out

A similar error was reported in [ptvsd github site](https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/317), the bug was resolved, but I have already the error. 
Did anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved unistalling and reinstalling QGIS 3.4.9 and following the instructions listed before.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a guide for OSX and Windows debugging with VSCode here:

OSX: [Debugging QGIS 3.x python plugins on OSX using VS Code](https://gist.github.com/AsgerPetersen/9ea79ae4139f4977c31dd6ede2297f90)

Windows: [Debugging QGIS 3.x python plugins on Windows 10 using VS Code](https://gist.github.com/NicolaiMogensen/acfd8723720c4761aefef3cdfc2aa55a)